# asp.net adding new records into webforms table

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I want to insert a record to a table in asp.net web forms, but couldn't figure it out. In PHP, it's easy just write html tags and loop them. but in asp.net is there a good way for this function?

I have a dropdown list and textbox, when I input the data and click add button, the selected value will go to the table first column and TextBox1 value will go to second column, if the client click add button again, system will check if the item is already there or not, if not it will add a new record.

Right now I could not have any idea about how to add record with updating the existing table. Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Are you using DataSource controls? something like this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource?view=netframework-4.7.2 and is the underlying database SQL?

Comment: no , just basic website, no database involved

Comment: So how so you populate the dropdown, is it just static menu items?
if there is no database involved once the page refreshes the values will be lost, are you saving these values somewhere? (This is how you can check if values have been added to a collection)

In terms of creating a table on runtime, you can create a nested loop with a StringBuilder and concatenate ("<tr>") and ("<td>") tags with the values in between.
i.e StringBuilder.Append("<td>" + item.value + "</td>")

Comment: Yes it is static menu,no database involved, but when I press add button, I am not redirecting to any other page or refresh them, so I think it should be OK to add the data I input when I hit add button, it should save into an array,array-list or something else so that an repeater might keep updating the records.